# Find and Replace multiple lines in notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

So I got a text file with over 100000 lines to find and replace. Here is what I need to find:

```
>>DiskNum: 118
adfad
adfadf
adfadf
adfad
adafdd
>>FilePath: \\xxx\xxx\abc.tif
```

Replace with:

```
>>DiskNum: 118
adfad
adfadf
adfadf
adfad
adafdd
>>FullPath: C:\abc\abc.tif
```

The goal is to find >>DiskNum: 118 and the replace will happen on 6 lines after >>DiskNum: 118

Is there anyway to do it in notepadd++??

Comment: Perhaps write a `perl` script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

*Find What*: `(^>>DiskNum: 118(?:\R.*){5}\R>>FilePath:\h*).*`
*Replace With*: `\1C:\\abc\\abc.tif`
*Regular expression*: CHECKED

**Details**:

- `(^>>DiskNum: 118(?:\R.*){5}\R>>FilePath:\h*)` - Group 1 (referenced with `\1` from the replacement pattern) capturing a sequence of:

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `>>startoDiskNum: 118` - a literal char sequence
  - `(?:\R.*){5}` - 5 lines (`\R` is a line break, and `.*` matches any 0+ chars other than line break chars)
  - `\R`  - line break
  - `>>FilePath:`  - a literal char sequence
  - `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `.*` - the rest of the line

[image]